# checking al checkboxes in pagination

Tags: jquery

I have a page that contains user list and checkboxes before each of them and there is a SELECT ALL button.The code works fine.  But the problem is that due to pagination, only the checkboxes in the current page gets selected, when i navigate to other pages via the pagination NEXT and PREVIOUS links, the checkboxes remain unchecked.  I cudnt find anything related to these or may be i was searching the wrong thing.  Please help.

i am using this code:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var checkbox = $(":checkbox");
checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? Are you going to other pages or just looking at a new list of data from a Datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, i figured out that datatables.js was being used and the correct way to select all checkboxes was using this piece of code:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function()({
  $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).each( function() {
    $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).attr('checked','checked');
  } );
});
```

It worked and now all checkboxes are getting selected, even on moving to other paginated pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(e) {
{
     var elements = ['#chk1' ,'#chk2','#chk3','#chk4','#chk5','#chk6'];
     jQuery.each(elements, function(element) {
          var checked = $(elements[element]).is(':checked');
         $(elements[element]).attr('checked', true);
     });
});
```