# Checking radios in pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have some radio buttons generated dynamically and are already paginated. Am checking to see if all are checked but this works only for the first page of pagination but fails to work for the next pages.

When i disable the pagination this works so it only checks for the radio buttons in the first page of the pagination but not all checkboxes how do i imlplement to check for all checkboxes regardless of which page they are in pagination

This is my code which works for first page of pagination

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {
   var all_answered = true;
   $("input:radio").each(function(){
      var name = $(this).attr("name");

      if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0)
      {
        all_answered = false;
      }
    });

  if(all_answered==true ){

      alert("all checked");


  }else {
      alert("not all checked");

  }

});
```

This is my php code that generates the radios:

```
<?php
 $n=1;
 foreach ($checks as $m => $check) {
  $radioyes ="";
  $radiono ="";
  $item ="";
  $radioyes .= '<input type="radio" name="'. $m.'" class="selected one"  value="'.$m.'" >';
   $radiono  .= '<input type="radio" name="'. $m .'" class="not_selected one"  value="'.$m.'">';

echo "<tr  id='" . $m . "'>";
echo "<td>" . $n . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";
echo "<td>".$radioyes."</td>";
echo "<td>".$radiono."</td>";
echo "<td>".$textinbox."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

$n++;
 }
 ?>
```

I hve checked on [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539481/checking-al-checkboxes-in-pagination) but doesnt work.

Comment: why the php and html tag if there's no relevant code?

Comment: What do you mean by relevant code?

Comment: what part of my question do you not understand; it's in plain English. You tagged as php and html and no (relevant) code in the question. All there is is jquery/js. Unless you want us to write it "for you".

Comment: I hve added the php code but i guess the php code is irrelevant in this situation since the checks are performed by jquery

Answer (score 0):

You have to use '.on('change'...) for dynamically generated inputs

E.g :

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function() {
  // Does some stuff 
});
```

Comment: even after that it still checks only the first page elements but the others are not checked